# Setting hot standby feedback for a specific query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, replication

I'm an R programmer trying to pull data from a PostgreSQL database for analysis, but started getting this error.

> ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
>   DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.

Looking around on here, seems like this is because the rows are changing as they are being queried, and the proposed solution by most answers is to use `hot_standby_feedback=on`. However, this seems to be a server setting, and not something I can set for that specific query. My question is, is there a way that I can enable this setting for my specific query? I found the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` commands [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-set-transaction.html) and tried them with `READ UNCOMMITTED` (at the suggestion of another online answer), but didn't work. Meaning, I started the query with: `BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`

Comment: The `context` field in [pg_settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-settings.html) tells you exactly where/when/how you can change each setting. `hot_standby_feedback` has context `sighup`, meaning it can only be changed in the server .conf file.

Comment: Note also that `READ UNCOMMITTED` is not actually implemented in Postgres; they accept this piece of syntax for the sake of compliance with the SQL standard, but the behaviour is identical to the default `READ COMMITTED`.